# Selecting all lines in an Illustrator document

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have about 50+ artboards in my Illustrator file with a lot of lines on them. All lines are currently 0.7px thick. I want all lines to be 2px thick.

How do I select all the lines (and not other elements) in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try selecting one of the lines and try navigating to Select > Same > Appearance.

Not sure if you can select all the artboards simultaneously, and if you have some grouping going on you need be sure your on a correct layer level.

Hope this helps. Have a great day,

-M

Answer (score 1):

First, unlock all elements (if any are locked) and unlock all the layers on which you have those lines. Then go to select - same - stroke weight.